# Grafana extract value from transformed column in group by

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have an instant query that returns some data that looks like this on Prometheus and want to visualize this as a bar chart in Grafana.

```
timeout=a, browser=chrome, value=1
timeout=b, browser=chrome, value=2
timeout=a, browser=safari, value=4
timeout=b, browser=safari, value=2
```

It measures the `value` for each combination of `browser` and `timeout`.

I want to display this data in a bar chart (with a bar per browser) and to have `timeout` on the x-axis and `value` on the y-axis.

### grafana

If I apply `group by` transformation on `timeout` field and apply `calculate (all unique values)` on the `browser` field, I get a table like this

```
| timeout | browser(uniqueValues)
---------------------------------
| a       |  [“chrome”, “safari”]
| b       |  [“chrome”, “safari”]
```

I then apply `extract fields` transformation on `browser(uniqueValues)` and I get:

```
| timeout | browser(uniqueValues) | chrome | safari
----------------------------------------------------
| a       |  [“chrome”, “safari”] | chrome | safari
| b       |  [“chrome”, “safari”] | chrome | safari
```

How do I get the actual value of `chrome` and `safari`?
What I expect is

```
| timeout | browser(uniqueValues) | chrome | safari
----------------------------------------------------
| a       |  [“chrome”, “safari”] | 1      | 4
| b       |  [“chrome”, “safari”] | 2      | 2
```